# Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS 10 / HTTP/2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, http, iis-8.5, http2

We're currently running Windows Server 2012 R2 for our web server, using IIS 8.5.
Is it possible to upgrade that to IIS 10 for HTTP/2 or otherwise enabled HTTP/2 on our current install?

Thanks, Matt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, IIS is a integrated part of the OS and can't be separately upgraded to a newer version. HTTP/2 especially isn't implemented in IIS, but in a [kernel mode driver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/new-features-introduced-in-iis-10) that is naturally only available in Win 10/2016.

Note: IIS 10 Express exists (and can be installed on that OS), but this is a testing/development server not meant for production use.

Comment: Ah thats a shame. Oh well. Ty.

Comment: We are currently using Windows 2012 on development servers. Are there any downsides or limitations with IIS 10 Express? Within a year, we will be shifting to newer servers with the latest Windows server operating system before we deploy, but would like to get some experience with IIS 10 on external test servers. Thanks....